# $a$ is a limit point of $[\alpha , \beta]$ if and only if $a \in [\alpha , \beta] $

Tags: real-analysis

$a$ is a limit point of $[\alpha , \beta]$ if and only if $a \in [\alpha , \beta] $

For the first part i suppose that $a$ is not in $[\alpha, \beta]$ then $a \in [\alpha, \beta]^c$
and how $[\alpha, \beta]$ is closed then $[\alpha, \beta]^c$ is open, so it must exist  some $p>0$ such that $B_p(a)\subset [\alpha, \beta]^c$ this implies that $B_p(a) \cap [\alpha, \beta]=\emptyset$
which contradicts that $a$ is a limit point of $[\alpha, \beta]$ is this right? and how can i prove the reverse?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know already that $[a, b]$ is closed, that direction of the proof is correct. (Indeed, for any closed set $A$, we have that the limit points of $A$ are elements of $A$ itself.)

---

For the other direction, here's a sketch: let $x \in [a, b]$ and $p > 0$ be arbitrary. You want to show that $(B_p(x) \setminus \{x\}) \cap [a, b]$ is nonempty.

Assuming $x \neq b$, do you see any obvious candidate in the intersection? What about $x + \frac{p}{2}$? Well, that would not work if $p$ is "large" (make this precise). But for those "large" $p$, we can simply see that $b$ is in the intersection.
Similarly, take care of the case $x = b$.